# Nim Game - Stack Selection

Tags: c++, arrays

We have to work on a game of Nim in C++ for Uni and I'm working through it fairly well its just I'm having a problem where when the player selects a stack it works in array numbers rather the numbers on the screen. I'm pretty sure it's just a "-1" somewhere however I cant find it, anywhere I try to place "-1" it ends up taking one of the final counter count.

Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


char star = '*';
const int HEAPS = 3;
int heaps[HEAPS];
int heapNumber[] = {1,2,3};
int playerHeapChoice;
int playerCounterChoice;

int playerTurn()
{
    std::cout << "Which stack would you like to take counters from?";
    std::cin >> playerHeapChoice;
    std::cout << "How many counters would you like to take from the heap?";
    std::cin >> playerCounterChoice;

    heaps[playerHeapChoice] = heaps[playerHeapChoice] - playerCounterChoice;
    std::cout << "There are " << heaps[playerHeapChoice] << " counters left in this stack.";

    return heaps[playerHeapChoice];
}

int main()
{   
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < HEAPS; i++)
    {
        heaps[i] = (rand() % 20) + 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Stack" << std::setw(8) << "  Number" << std::setw(8) << "   Counters" <<     std::endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < HEAPS; count++)
    {
         std::cout << heapNumber[count] << std::setw(8) << heaps[count] << std::setw(8);
         for (int count = 0; count < heaps[count]; count++)
        {
            std::cout << star;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    playerTurn();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems I see. `for (int count = 0; count < heaps[count]; count++)` You reuse `count` in both loops. Change the inner one to something like `for (int drawcount = 0; drawcount < heaps[count]; drawcount++)`. The other big problem is that you ask the user for a number 1,2,3 . That is one based. You have to access the arrays zero based. After `std::cin >> playerHeapChoice;` decrement playerHeapChoce by one before usage  with something like `playerHeapChoice--;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that instead of

```
std::cout << heapNumber[count]
```

you can do

```
std::cout << (count + 1)
```

Similarly, part of your problem is with

```
heaps[playerHeapChoice]
```

which should be

```
heaps[playerHeapChoice - 1]
```

Also, I strongly suggest that you declare each variable inside the function where it is used. Declaring all of your variables as globals is frowned upon as it can cause serious issues in larger programs.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable name int count twice.

Once in the first for loop and once in the second. I am surprised that compiled. But I am sure it is causing issues.

```
for (int count = 0; count < HEAPS; count++)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < heaps[count]; count++)
    {
    }
}
```

As for your issue it is hard to understand the question? Is it that you are asking players what stack to take from and the number they input is getting the array index instead of the actual stack with that number of things?

If so its because you are accessing the array directly by the index they type. You need to be finding the value inside of the array. Psuedo Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < heaps[count]; ++count)
{
    if(heaps[i] == playerHeapChoice)
    {
        std::cout << "There are " << heaps[i] << " counters left in this stack.";
    }
}
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: `I am surprised that compiled.` It's called "shadowing".

Comment: I am sure this is along the right lines although im unsure where to  place it as basically the program works. It prints the 3 stacks and I have them labelled as "1, 2, 3" thanks to the heapNumber array but if the player selects heap 1 it selects heap 2 so yeah they are getting the array index instead of the actual stack although I have no idea where to put that if statement as there is no count in the playerTurn method.

Comment: In that case I would do as the previous user mentioned. Arrays start at index 0 while the player will probably not type it in that way. So remove 1 from what the player types in.